# iPhone: hiding a custom view under the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, calayer

For the app I working on, I am implementing a control that is similar to the notification view on iOS. So, I am working on dragging a view down from under the navigation bar of the UIViewController.

My question is whether there's a way to position a view that is MOSTLY hidden under the navigation bar?? The goal is to have just a few pixels visible, so that there's a way to grab it and drag down.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, resolved this issue myself. Turns out what works for me is having a custom view and then adding that view in IB in the order where nav bar comes after that custom view.

Another trick was to figure out how to initialize/embed that custom view and for that I found help here: [UIView subclass with its own XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246074/uiview-subclass-with-its-own-xib)