# Creating and loading Views with another UIView in the Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard with multiple `UIViews`.

Inside one of my `UIViews` I add additional sub-views. I essentially drag and drop `UITableViews`,`UIViews` etc inside the same `UIViewController`. See the screenshot below:

[image: HORRIBLE LOOKING VIEW]

How can I create these views as separate entities of the storyboard but then.. load them into a particular `UIView`?

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: question is not clear, what is your issue?

Comment: you want to create separate views and load them in you view controller right?

Comment: yeah, should I use .xib files? if so.. how can I load them into the UIViewController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard this might help if you want to create subview in storyboard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814928/how-to-load-a-xib-file-in-a-uiview this is for loading view from xib

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use a container. You can embed another UIViewController in a container via right click -> embed -> drag to desired UIViewController
You can even use this UIViewController in multiple containers this way (reusing).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to do this would be to subclass the UIViews you want to reuse and declare their interfaces as separate xibs. Then initialize them in your ViewController and then add/position them to the base UIView with `addSubview:`

See this SO answer for more of an explanation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12880151/902730